# Easy way to check Dagger 2 dependency cycle?

Tags: android, dependencies, cycle, dagger

Here.

So after bit of refactoring in my project I've ended up with the dependency cycle SOMEWHERE. My module with `@Provided` dependencies is huge and it's really hard to understand what exactly is the cause.

Here is console log:
http://pastebin.com/yxDDEHgz

As you can see it's huge and doesn't tell me nothing. Is there any way to quickly check which dependency injection causes a cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to pay attention to the lines starting with `[parameter: …`

if you attention you see your cycle is like below:

```
line 16: [parameter: packagename.map.mapservice.IMapService mapService]

line 13: [parameter: packagename.lib.common.IApplicationVisibility mapVisibility]

line 9: [parameter: packagename.lib.notifications.INotificationSettings notificationSettings]

line 7: [parameter: packagename.map.mapcontent.MarkerClickHandler markerClickHandler]

line 5: [parameter: packagename.map.mapservice.IMapService mapService]
```

and here you trying to re-inject `IApplicationVisibility` so cycle is here :

```
line 3: [injected field of type: packagename.lib.common.IApplicationVisibility applicationVisibility]
```

IMapService -> IApplicationVisibility -> INotificationSettings -> MarkerClickHandler -> IMapService (again IMapService !!!) -> IApplicationVisibility

you injected `IMapService` again in `MarkerClickHandler` which starts the **cycle** !!

Comment: Thanks man. I've been fixing it through trial and error since the log was useless for me. Now I will know : )

Comment: yes there is always a bit of big-log-phobia in all programmers :D even in meh :D but when it comes to solving others' problems all of us are masters of everything :))